# submit form with ajax but get "Illegal Invocation"

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, ajaxform

I try to submit form via ajax, below is the form.

```
<form class="form-vertical" method="POST" id="request-form" action="/post_handler?request=add_data" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date_inp" class="control-label">Date</label>
      <input class="form-control hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" type="text" name="date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file_inp">Upload File</label>
    <div>
      <input class="form-control" id="file_inp" type="file" placeholder="Upload File" name="file">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-button" onclick="on_click_form_submit(event);">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the click function.

```
on_click_form_submit = function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form_data = new FormData($('#request-form')[0]),
        form_url = '/' + $('#request-form')[0].action.split('/').pop();

    console.log('url: ' + form_url);
    $.ajax({
            url: form_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            alert(response);
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });

    return false;
};
```

When I click submit, it reports

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
  at add (jquery-1.9.1.js:7340)
  at buildParams (jquery-1.9.1.js:7392)
  at Function.jQuery.param (jquery-1.9.1.js:7360)
  at Function.ajax (jquery-1.9.1.js:7863)
  at Object.on_click_form_submit (spa.shell.js:301)
```

Comment: You get this when you pass something invalid to the AJAX, and it sounds like `form_url` is wrong. Does that evaluate correctly?

Comment: What is you're endpoint expecting a object or a string?
 At a glance that looks like a string. I'd consider taking the time to create a model and pass that to the server. +1 for using fail, nothing i hate more than someone ignoring handling errors even if it is just an alert :P

Comment: Object I think, I am not really sure because I just feed the request to formidable and let it spit out form fields for me. Check my another related Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888112/collect-multiple-inputs-file-to-append-to-formdata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), jQuery's `$.ajax` accepts:

> Type: PlainObject or String or Array

So, your `form_data` should be in one of those formats - it should not be an instantiation of a `FormData`. It depends on what your backend is expecting, but one option would be to convert the form's values to an object with `serializeArray()`:

```js
on_click_form_submit = function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var form_data = $('#request-form').serializeArray(),
    form_url = '/' + $('#request-form')[0].action.split('/').pop();

  console.log('url: ' + form_url);
  $.ajax({
      url: form_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: form_data,
      dataType: 'json',
      encode: true
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      alert(response);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    });

  return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-vertical" method="POST" id="request-form" action="/post_handler?request=add_data" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date_inp" class="control-label">Date</label>
    <input class="form-control hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" type="text" name="date">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file_inp">Upload File</label>
    <div>
      <input class="form-control" id="file_inp" type="file" placeholder="Upload File" name="file">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-button" onclick="on_click_form_submit(event);">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your substantial explanation, very helpful!

Comment: Well, on a second thought, I feel "serialize" may not be needed as shown by other similar questions, where "new FormData" can be directly embedded into ajax request. On the other hand, I found that my browser does not fully support HTML5. I use this website https://html5test.com/ for the test which shows my browser does not support direct upload.