# collect multiple inputs file to append to FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, ajaxform

Suppose I have the following form.

```
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="file" name="uploads[]"><br/>
  <input type="file" name="uploads[]"><br/>
  <input type="file" name="uploads[]"><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is part of the submit code which tries to collect files to append to FormData, but I don't know how to do it properly.

```
var formData = new FormData();

var fileList = $("input[name='uploads[]']");
for(var x = 0; x < fileList.length; x++) {
  formData.append('file'+x, ???);
  console.log('appended a file');
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/upload');
request.send(formData);

request.onload = function(e) {
  console.log('Request Status', request.status);
};
```

This is the server code.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log('handling form upload - fields', fields);
    console.log('handling form upload - files', files);
  });
  res.send('Thank you');
});
```

If it works, I expect to see output and files saved in /tmp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to collect fields since you can put the form itself into `FormData` object:

```
var form = document.getElementById('testForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', '/upload');

  request.onload = function(e) {
    console.log('Request Status', request.status);
  };

  var formData = new FormData(form);
  request.send(formData);
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to upload several files, you might use `multiple` attribute on the input instead of several inputs:

```
<form id="testForm">
  <input type="file" name="upload" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I try this before and somehow it doesn't work. I have a feeling that FormData does not include files and when I append explicitly it works but I just don't know how to append multiple files as array under the same name. I add the server side code. Could you help take a look? Thank you.

Comment: @user180574, I've updated my answer regarding multiple files upload. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with backend code like yours, but I suggest to check what `req`, `res`, `form` variables are. Probably you have to put `req` into `IncomingForm()`. Please look at your backend documentation.

Comment: OK, it works and you are right. I only need FormData(...) and that's it. Somehow with various attempts, I accidentally removed "name" attribute in input tag which turns out to be an important attribute.

Comment: BTW, I haven't tried the multiple files because since FormData can include the whole form, I don't need the solution of multiple files anymore. THANKS!

Comment: @user180574, happy to help!